# Clone a git repository into an InMemoryRepository with JGit

Tags: git, jgit

I need to clone an existing git repository into an `InMemoryRepository`, using JGit, change a file's content and push the changes back to the remote repository.

I couldn't find any examples of cloning a repository into an in-memory repository.

I tried this:

```java
InMemoryRepository.Builder builder = new InMemoryRepository.Builder();  
InMemoryRepository inm = builder.build(); 
Git.cloneRepository().setURI("git@[github_url].git").setDirectory(inm.getDirectory()).call();
```

Which resulted in an **error**:

> 'Destination path ".git" already exists and is not an empty
>   directory'.

I checked the configuration options for `InMemoryRepository.Builder` and `Repository` classes, but haven't found anything useful.

How can it be done? And after that, is there any problem with changing a file's content and pushing it to github, all from the in-memory repository?

Comment: Its because `inm.getDirectory()` returns null, so effectively  you are not setting directory at all. Just ran trought this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CloneCommand` will always create a file-based repository. The lines from your post that create an `InMemoryRepository` have no effect on the clone command.

I suggest to clone into a temporary location if you only need the repository to make a change and push the result.

For example:

```java
Git.cloneRepository().setURI( ... ).setDirectory( new File("/path/to/empty/dir" ) ).call();
```

An `InMemoryRepository` in JGit still requires a work directory for operations like checkout, etc. Only the object database which is usually found in the `.git` directory is stored in memory

Comment: If I don't set a directory to the `CloneCommand`, where is the file-based repository saved?
And is the `InMemoryRepository` only used for new repositories? (which are obviously not saved)

Comment: If no directory is set, the `CloneCommand` will choose a directory (the the current program working directory plus the repository name, see the JavaDoc). And yes, the `InMemoryRepository` in its current state is very limited in its practical use and only meant for experimental or testing purposes.

Answer (score 7):

There is a proper solution without any files on disk, even temporary:

```java
    // sample usage
    private void loadFromGit() throws Exception {
        ObjectLoader loader = loadRemote("https://github.com/msangel/promisified-resource-loader", "master", "README.md");
        loader.copyTo(System.out);
    }

    private ObjectLoader loadRemote(String uri, String branch, String filename) throws Exception {
        DfsRepositoryDescription repoDesc = new DfsRepositoryDescription();
        InMemoryRepository repo = new InMemoryRepository(repoDesc);
        Git git = new Git(repo);
        git.fetch()
                .setRemote(uri)
                .setRefSpecs(new RefSpec("+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*"))
                .call();
        repo.getObjectDatabase();
        ObjectId lastCommitId = repo.resolve("refs/heads/"+ branch);
        RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk(repo);
        RevCommit commit = revWalk.parseCommit(lastCommitId);
        RevTree tree = commit.getTree();
        TreeWalk treeWalk = new TreeWalk(repo);
        treeWalk.addTree(tree);
        treeWalk.setRecursive(true);
        treeWalk.setFilter(PathFilter.create(filename));
        if (!treeWalk.next()) {
            return null;
        }
        ObjectId objectId = treeWalk.getObjectId(0);
        ObjectLoader loader = repo.open(objectId);
        return loader;
    }
```

So, actually you have TreeWalk here (which is default to recursive), but you can change this and manually iterate all from repo.

Comment: This is a nice exmaple of getting the repo into memory. But the OP also wants to know how to change a file and commit it to repo all in memory. At least I want to know it :)

Answer (score 1):

Also, with a small tweak on previous answer:

- Listing all files in commit
- Filtering files by extension

  ```
  public Function<String, List<String>> lastCommitFiles = (extension) -> {

  final List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
  try {

      ...

      try (TreeWalk walk = new TreeWalk(inMemoryRepository)) {
          walk.addTree(revTree);
          walk.setRecursive(true);
          walk.setPostOrderTraversal(true);
          while (walk.next()) {
              if ((extension != null && extension.length() > 0)) {
                  if (walk.getPathString().lastIndexOf(extension) != -1) {
                      paths.add(walk.getPathString());
                  }
              } else paths.add(walk.getPathString());
          }
      }
      return paths;
  } catch (GitAPIException | IOException e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage());
  }

  return paths;
  ```

  };