# java git-library with configurable in-memory FileSystem

Tags: java, git, filesystems, jimfs

Is there a java-library that operates on a user-provided `java.nio.file.FileSystem` ?

I'm using googles jimfs in-memory-filesystem implementation and would like to clone a git repository into my filesystem and perform a complex series of operations but don't touch the disk.

Unfortunately it does not seem like jgit-api provides the possibility to operate on a FileSystem of choice.

EDIT:

The reason for the incompatibility between jgit and jimfs seems to be in the fact that jgit's api uses the file and jimfs uses paths as its main abstraction. Unfortunately jimfs does not implement `Path.toFile()`.
Any technical reasons for that ?

Comment: The question is unclear.  Isn't jimfs a "user-provided" Filesystem?

Comment: yes, but jgit api seems not to operate on user-provided filesystems.

Comment: So you want a different jgit library that works with `java.nio.file.FileSystem`... that might be hard to find.  It may be easier to create a RAM disk instead and have it operate on that.

Comment: I want this too!

Comment: +1 JGit is a good Git implementation, but it works on `File` rather than `Path`, which prevents it from working on JimFS.

Comment: See jGit example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31271278/clone-a-git-repository-into-an-inmemoryrepository-with-jgit/54486558#54486558