# Clone git repository in-memory

Tags: java, git, jgit, jimfs

I've been trying to clone a tiny git configuration repository into memory using [JGIT](https://eclipse.org/jgit/) and [JIMFS](https://github.com/google/jimfs) using something like

```
FileSystem fs = Jimfs.newFileSystem(Configuration.unix());
Path gitPath = Files.createDirectories(fs.getPath("/git")); 
Git.cloneRepository().setURI(...).setBranch(...).setDirectory(gitPath.toFile())
                    .setCredentialsProvider(...).call()
```

But since JIMFS works with the path [Path API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) (since it doesn't use the default Filesystem), while JGIT uses the [File API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html), JIMFS doesn't implement to toFile() call:

```
@Override
public File toFile() {
    // documented as unsupported for anything but the default file system
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

So I get is this `UnsupportedOperationException`. Is there a simple way of getting this (or a similar) setup to work without resorting to a temp directory on the disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JGit offers an `InMemoryRepository` for testing and experimental use. But even this repository backend would store the work directory of non-bare repositories on disk.

Unless JGit changes its `FileRepository` implementation to use the Paths API, I don't see a way to use Jimfs to store repositories.

Some commands allow specifying a `WorkingTreeIterator`, which in theory, would allow read-access to a working tree on an alternate storage. However, not all commands support this concept write-access is also currently missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone repository into memory and copy it file by file to own fs.
See example of reading files into internal in memory repo here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54486558/449553